# How to create rounded TV edges effect in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d

Is there a way to get rounded TV edges like these:
[image]

I want rounded egdes and the distortion effect, but I can't find a way to do this. I am using Unity 2017.

Comment: You probably want to use search engine for a thing called barrel distortion.

Comment: In this particular screenshot, it doesn't look like there's any bending/warping of the main game scene (see how the pixel lines stay ruler-straight), so this is probably just an image of the TV frame drawn over-top after the the rest of the scene has rendered. Did you try doing something like that?

Comment: I agree, I would create the image in a image editor of choice and brush the inside to be transparent adding the curve just how you want. Then you can import that into the project and overlay the game screen.